# How to solve ImportError on import cv2 without uninstalling

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, python-3.5

I've installed OpenCV3 from source and after running `import cv2` I get the error:

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/Victor/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.5/cv2.so,    2): Symbol not found: _PyCObject_Type
    Referenced from: /Users/Victor/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.5/cv2.so
    Expected in: flat namespace
in /Users/Victor/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.5/cv2.so
```

I really want to do this without reinstalling OpenCV,  because I don't want to go through that again. If it helps at all I'm on my path is `PYTHONPATH="/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.1/"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I solved this was taking the cv2.cpython-35m-darwin.so file from the opencv/build/lib directory and putting it in place of cv2.so in my virtualenv folder

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.1:$PYTHONPATH`